# parse cloud code installation on yosemite

Tags: command-line, parse-platform

I have previously installed the Cloud Code tools on mac before upgrading to Yosemite. Now when installing with the following command

curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash

that I found on the most recent documentation on the parse site i get the following error.

/bin/bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'bin/bash: line 2:`301 Moved Permanently

I have also just entered "https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh" into a browser and ran the shell script. It states that it is installing and it creates a directory in /usr/local/bin/ and contains the file "parse" with no extension.

When i examine the file in VI i see the following text.

I have previously installed the Cloud Code tools on mac before upgrading to Yosemite. Now when installing with the following command

curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash

that I found on the most recent documentation on the parse site i get the following error.

/bin/bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'bin/bash: line 2:`301 Moved Permanently

I have also just entered "https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh" into a browser and ran the shell script. It states that it is installing and it creates a directory in /usr/local/bin/ and contains the file "parse" with no extension.

When i examine the file in VI i see the following text.

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong here..or could it be that something has actually been moved and the documentation is just not up to date?

Comment: ok its a bug they are working out as right now. see the following. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/iLLsXuN0PDc

Comment: They state the use the sL command so it will redirect but this does not work either. I guess they are still investigating.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just had the same problem (OS X 10.9.5). So it´s not OS related.

But I found out that you can do a manual install.

First download the install.sh file with a web browser.
Then check the file by right clicking it and check the file info or open it with a text editor.

In the file you see that it downloads the parse binary from here:
https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/parse

Download that file.

Start terminal and go to where you downloaded the file.

Enter:

mv parse /usr/local/bin/parse

chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/parse

Test that it is working.

Works for me! :-)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! But I could not find that file when reading `install.sh`

Comment: Lots of things has changed in 11 months. The installer.sh has changed. They open sourced the SDK in September. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/open-sourcing-our-sdks/ and moved everything to gitHub. Then they have rebuilt the CLI in go. I think it was built in Ruby or Python before (I could be wrong)...

Comment: i got this error: Error talking to the Parse servers; please try again.